# How to install Windows 2008 on a VHD on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, installation, vhd

I am trying to set up a Windows 2008 VDH that I can boot on my windows 7 machine.

So far I have created and formatted the VHD. I have also downloaded an iso image with windows 2008.

What I am wondering is:

- How do I boot from the vhd?
- How do I install windows 2008 from the iso image onto the vhd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out (from Scott Hanselman's blog)...

[Step-By-Step: Turning a Windows 7 DVD or ISO into a Bootable VHD Virtual Machine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StepByStepTurningAWindows7DVDOrISOIntoABootableVHDVirtualMachine.aspx)

Comment: He specified Server 2008.  Your answer referenced Windows 7.

Comment: i would assume steps for Windows 7 apply to Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 doesn't contain the drivers for booting from a VHD (except if you actually meant that you're booting Server 2008 in a VM.)

You can only boot directly from a VHD with Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7.